# Is there any way can I use chrome in different region without installing on AWS ec2 neither any other server

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have a website that is only accessible from the European Union. Let's say I've traveled to Asia and need to view some websites (booking tickets etc). because it states that this site is inaccessible from your current location

Do I make use of any other services besides AWS workspace/DAAS?

Comment: Did you contact the owner of the website and ask for the limitation to be lifted? If the access is needed for the purpose of your business they should have an open ear for that.

Comment: Hello, Tilman. This is not a question for the website's owner. This inquiry is open to any alternative that I can try to provide a broad range of access.
From a website standpoint, the establishment of an edge location cache will allow users to access a wider range of content/deploy it to the base region, that is expected answers, but which I am looking for user friendly.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a VPN. Some options are:

1. Install a VPN server in an allowed region and connect from your client. AWS and Digital Ocean might have some out-of-box VPN servers on the marketplace
2. Alternatively, you can try using some free VPN server like [VPN Gate](https://www.vpngate.net/en/)
3. Or choosing a cloud VPN service like ExpressVPN

Answer (score 2):

Create an [AWS Workspace virtual desktop](https://aws.amazon.com/workspaces/) in whichever region you need. Takes no time, there's a small monthly charge then it's hourly, or you can pay a single monthly charge if you use it a lot that works out better value.